# Cleanest solution to compile absolute imports in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, babeljs

I want to use absolute imports in Typescript so I can do something like this:

```
import something from "utils/subdir";
```

instead of

```
import something from "../../../utils/subdir";
```

I have the following configuration in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

However, when compiling, I get my Javascript files with absolute imports also. So I get something like this at the end of the day:

```
const something = require("utils/subdir");
```

And so I cannot use this because I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'utils/subdir'
```

My question is: what is the cleanest way to deal with this? I have read that we can first compile the code with `tsc` and then with `babel` or directly use `babel` to transpile the code. Is there any way not to use babel to solve this issue?

Comment: do you use ```webpack```?

Comment: I am not using `webpack`

Comment: you should read this - https://medium.com/@grrowl/fixing-absolute-imports-in-typescript-797f405176eb

Comment: I already read that, so there is no way to solve this problem in a simple way?